# Javascript - best way to handle post-load generated content

Tags: javascript

I've been wondering how to efficiently and generically process content that is generated after any user action.

For instance, let's say my script processes all paragraphs of Facebook at page load in order to make them blink. What would be the most responsive way to make the text that is displayed later (because of infinite scroll e.g.) blink ?

Thanks in advance for your ideas,

Rolf

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I define a function called `dom_mods()` that modifies the page in order to apply any special effects such as autocompletion, default value for `<select>`, auto-resizing textareas and so on. Whenever I add content to the document, I call `dom_mods()`.

The only catch is to make sure you don't affect the same elements twice, or if you do it needs to not make a difference. For instance, there might be a class that defines a set of elements to affect, so the class should be removed by `dom_mods()` so it doesn't get the treatement twice.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. The thing is, as the example suggests, the page on which the script is executed might not be mine (I do not own Facebook) and I cannot modify existing scripts to insert calls to my dom_mods function.

Answer (score 0):

You would add the blink function to the parent object that would encompass all the children.

In other words if you use jquery you would specify the event selector as (".parent .child") when registering the child blink event. This way, you don't need to register any additional jquery "dom_mods" function or call anything else which wastes memory and time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. That still leaves the problem of handling events I cannot know in advance (as I commented on Kolink answer, the script could run on a page I do not own).